# securesocial fake log in when developing

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am using securesocial it works fine but now every time I change some scala code I have to login again. Is there a possibility to fake a user in the session when in development mode, so I don't have to login so often?

Thanks,

Joris Wijlens

Comment: Strange... Are you clearing your cookies somewhere (in `Global.onStop()` or somewhere else) ?

Comment: Not that i am aware of. So this is not the default behaviour?

Comment: The problem went away after switching to a database implementation for the userservice

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That happens because in DEV mode Play restarts the app when you change your code.  So, the data in the sample user service is lost.

Answer (score 12):

SecureSocial by default uses the default Play cache for storing authenticators (that match the cookies to the logged in user).  The default play cache is EHCache and it's configured using the ehcache.xml that you can find in the jars.  The default configuration is strictly in memory which means that when the app restarts, it loses all the values.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy to overwrite the EHCache configuration to write to the disk.

Copy the ehcache.xml in the jars to your configuration directory.  Add `<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>` and change `diskPersistent` to `true`

So mine looks like this:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />
</ehcache>
```

If you're interested learning how to configure the rest of it, there is some documentation in the ehcache-failsafe.xml file that's also in the Play jars.

Comment: For Play 2.2, I found the ehcache-default.xml file in play/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/resources/.  I renamed it to ehcache.xml and put it in the conf directory of my project.  I just set diskPersistent to true and it worked.  Not sure if the <diskStore path ...> part is necessary though.